# Quadratic Sequence tree branching node help

Tags: nodes, trees, seq

I want to make something like this. [image: Quadratic Sequence]

I tried using tree diagrams and got this code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{geometry}
% \usepackage{poker}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm
 }
 \settasks{
  style = enumerate ,
  counter-format = tsk),
  label-align = right,
  label-width = 2em,
  label-offset = .75em
  %label-format = \bfseries
}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}

% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=6cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=3cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=up, sloped]
\node {}
    child {
        node[bag] {$2a$}
        child {
            node[bag] {$5a+b$}
            child {
                node {$16a+4b+c$}
            }
            child {
                node {$9a+3b+c$}
            }
        }
        child {
            node[bag] {$3a+b$}
            child {
                node {$4a+2b+c$}
            }
            child {
                node {$a+b+c+d$}
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields this result:[image: my version]

The problem with this is if I do another set that includes another 2a, those two 2a's will branch into one node. How should I change my code?

Comment: Welcome! Can you remove irrelevant stuff from your preamble? I'm not really sure what you mean by branching into one node. Generally, tree-drawing packages are designed for trees, which have a single root. It might be easier to use the `matrix` library.

Comment: You can use a phantom root (and the standard `trees` doesn't care anyway), but the real problem is that tree nodes have at most one parent each and not, as in the case of biological organisms, two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trees have a single root and every non-root node has one parent. Generally, packages designed to draw trees are specialised software for drawing trees in this sense and not, say, more generalised graphs. The Ti*k*Z library doesn't mind multiple roots, but it is still tricky to deal with multiple parents and so on.

I think it would be easier to think of the diagram as a matrix with some edges drawn between some of the nodes.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes]
  {
    & n=1 && n=2 && n=3 && n=4\\
   T_n & a+b+c && 4a+2b+c && 9a+3b+c && 16a+4b+c\\
   \text{1\textsuperscript{st} difference} & & 3a+b && 5a+b && 7a+b & \\
   \text{2\textsuperscript{nd} difference} & & & 2a && 2a &&\\
  };
  \draw (M-2-2) -- (M-3-3) -- (M-4-4) -- (M-3-5) edge (M-2-4) edge (M-2-6) -- (M-4-6) -- (M-3-7) edge (M-2-6) -- (M-2-8) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: i would draw line as `\draw   (M-2-2) -- (M-3-3) -- (M-2-4) -- (Mm-3-5) -- (M-2-6) -- (M-3-7) -- (M-2-8)
        (M-3-3) -- (M-4-4) -- (M-3-5) -- (M-4-6) -- (M-3-7);` ... you were faster than me for few minutes :(

Comment: @Zarko Too much typing :-).